# fetch only 'enabled' records from the database in cakephp v1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is there any way of fetching only those records of a model which have 'status = 1' in cakephp v1.3 ?

I have created a field named 'status' in every table of my web application.

I have a model named 'Message'. What I want is that only those messages are displayed, included in search results which have 'status = 1'. Messages with a 'status = 0' won't be displayed and won't be included in search results too.

Please help me if I can do it the cakePHP way, for now as a temporary solution I am using the 'status = 1' in the conditions array of every find of messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd include this in the `beforeFind()` callback method. You can include it in the callback for every model (but only once for each model--not for each *query*) or you can apply it to your `AppModel` so that all of your other models inherit it.

In the `beforeFind()` callback, you can modify the structure of the query. In this case, you'd apply the condition `array( 'status' => 1 )` to your incoming query. Dump the argument data structure to see what's coming in and I think it will make sense to you.

Note that if you chose to do this in your `AppModel` and have to create a model-specific `beforeFind` callback in the future, you'll need to be sure that you call `parent::beforeFind()` in your subclass' `beforeFind()` method.

Comment: the main problem of this method is that when I am using $this->paginate['Message'] for showing up my messages in the index action then I again have to again write the condition "Message.status = '1' " :-(
cakephp guys should include this functionality in upcoming version.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer over **[here](http://cakeqs.org/eng/questions/view/fetch_only_%E2%80%98enabled%E2%80%99_records_from_the_database_in_cakephp_v1_3)** The beforeFind() callback comes handy for this.

like this

```
public function beforeFind($conditions) {
    if(!isset($conditions['conditions']['Message.status']) && !isset($conditions['conditions']['status'])) {
        $conditions['conditions']['Message.status'] = 1;
    }
    return $conditions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are speaking for Soft deletable behavior. There is one [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/soft-delete-behavior) For me it's not perfect, but for simple app it could do the job. In the comments you can see the improvements too :)

But extending the beforeFind() in the AppModel should be ok too.