# Cake PHP Common Code in Before Filter Function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using Cakephp 1.3
As i have multiple controllers

like , Score, Stundets etc..

in score i have multiple functions with differents conditions 
Now what i need i want to add some logic in before filter function that to show only field is_deleted =0

I am trying this code

```
$this->Score->Student->conditions='Student.is_deleted=>0';
```

As passing all conditions too all function is too time Consuming

This above code is not working. I want to add filter So i will work in whole project

Anybody have an idea

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [beforeFind() method](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1049/beforeFind) in your `Student` model instead of putting your conditions logic in `beforeFilter()` method.

Write this code into `Student Model`:

```
function beforeFind($queryData)
{
    if (!isset($queryData['conditions'])) {
        $queryData['conditions'] = array();
    }       
    $queryData['conditions'][$this->alias.'.is_deleted'] = '0';       
    return $queryData;
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138389/fetch-only-enabled-records-from-the-database-in-cakephp-v1-3) might also help you to achieve the same.

You can also use [Behavior Callbacks](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1641/Creating-a-behavior-callback).

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Can you please provide exact example , As still i am not able to do this